# jQuery selector stores object? How to force it not to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a dropdown ( < select > ) element and a container.

```
<div class='container' />
<script>
   var dropdown = "<select class='multi-dropdown'> ... </select>"
</script>
```

When the value is changed, You get another of it.
It is logical, that this only happens when the document is ready ( the first one is made there ), and when the client modifies the last one.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('.container').append(dropdown);
    $('.multi-dropdown:last').change(function(){
          $('.container').append(dropdown);
    }); 
});
```

Seems to be a working code for me. But what I noticed is, this is not working with the next appended dropdown element. Also if I change the original one, it fires.

**My theory is, maybe jQuery already stored the original object as the :last , so it won't select a new element again even if I add new "last" ones.**

or

**The freshly created element ( this way ) isn't even selectable with jQuery.**

Please argue in favor, or against, these are just my ideas.

Comment: Why are you using `:last`?

Comment: That is not how jQuery works.  Also note that using a self-closing tag (`<div class='container'/>`) **will not work** in some document types. It'll be parsed, but it will not be treated as a closed element in an HTML document.

Comment: Because you are attaching the change handler to the current :last element, if it changes dynamically it will not be changed accordingly; try delegation instead. Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are binding the `change` handler to the `:last` element at page startup, if the last element changes dynamically it will not be changed accordingly; try and read deeply delegation using [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method instead.

Like:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('.container').append(dropdown);
    $('body').on('change','.multi-dropdown:last',function(){
        $('.container').append(dropdown);
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're newly appended SELECT doesn't ever get an event bound to it.  Just because you used the class to bind the change even for the initial SELECT, that doesn't automatically apply to every newly added element to the DOM.

Read up on delegated events, like for the [on() function](http://api.jquery.com/on/).  Or use something like [livequery](https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery).

Comment: Yeah, that's my exact problem. But please, could You explain me, how to select a new element? Because it's not just about binding the event linstener, but selecting the fresh element itself.

Comment: No, it's about event delegation.  Go read the link I gave you for the on() function.